# Searching mongo document by element which is array

Tags: java, mongodb, bson

How to convert that query to java code (bson filter)?

`db.getCollection('cache').find({'geometry.coordinates':[19.045258, 49.804283]})`

Comment: Why dont you use MongoRepositoty `findBy..()` jpa method?

Comment: See examples using [MongoDB Java Driver - Geospatial Queries](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver/tutorials/geospatial-search/).